# How can I pass session value to subdomain

Tags: php, session

Is there any option to pass session variable from one sub domain to another?

I need this to implement in a chat application.

Comment: Set your session cookie as a domain cookie (e.g. `.mydomain.com`), and it will then be accessible from the domain and all its subdomains

Comment: or you can store your session in DB and can share it with multiple domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php). You need to set the parameter `domain`.

> Cookie domain, for example 'www.php.net'. To make cookies visible on
>   all subdomains then the domain must be prefixed with a dot like
>   '.php.net'.

So your code will be something like this

```
session_set_cookie_params(60*24, '/', '.yourdomain.com');
session_start();
```